# Unity Netcode's ClientRpc is not being sent across the network

Tags: unity-game-engine, rpc, multiplayer, unity-networking

I copy and pasted Unity Netcode's example code from https://docs-multiplayer.unity3d.com/docs/advanced-topics/message-system/clientrpc to test it out. This is my exact code:

```
public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public TMP_Text text;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.P))
        {
            PongClientRpc(Time.frameCount, "hello, world"); // Server -> Client
        }
    }
    [ClientRpc]
    void PongClientRpc(int somenumber, string sometext)
    {
        text.text = $"{somenumber} : {sometext}";
        Debug.Log(text.text);
    }
}
```

What I've found is that the function just acts as a normal function whether it's called on the host application or client application, and it is never transmitted across the network. My expectation is that when it is called on the host application, the RPC would be transmitted to the client application and executed there as well, thus reflecting a change in the TMP_Text object, but clearly this is not the case.

Just to check all the boxes, this script is attached to a `GameObject` that also has a `NetworkObject` component. For good measure, I tested the `TMP_Text` object both with and without a `NetworkObject` component attached. In all cases, any object with a `NetworkObject` component was properly added to the `NetworkManager`'s network prefabs list.

I'm starting to question if I even understand what an RPC is or how it's supposed to work. Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This class needs to be derived from `NetworkBehavior` not `MonoBehaviour` else it won't be networked.

Make sure to  add `using Unity.Netcode;` at the top of the class.